Proof explanation: how to see that $(u_n)$ is bounded above by $v_0$
I am new to this and I am trying understand this proof of Monotone-sequences property $⇒$ least upper bound property.

Let $A$ be a non-empty set that's bounded above. Pick $u_0, v_0$ such that $u_0$ is not an upper bound for $A$ and $v_0$ is an upper bound. Now do a repeated bisection: having chosen $u_n$ and $v_n$ such that $u_n$ is not an upper bound and $v_n$ is, if $(u_n + v_n)/2$ is an upper bound, then let $u_{n + 1} = u_n$, $v_{n + 1} = (u_n + v_n)/2$. Otherwise, let $u_{n + 1} = (u_n + v_n)/2$, $v_{n + 1} = v_n$.
Then $u_0 \leq u_1 \leq u_2 \leq \cdots$ and $v_0\geq v_1 \geq v_2 \geq \cdots$. We also have
$v_n - u_n = \frac{v_0 - u_0}{2^n} \to 0.$ By the monotone sequences property, $u_n\to s$ (since $(u_n)$ is bounded above by $v_0$). Since $v_n - u_n \to 0$, $v_n \to s$. We now show that $s = \sup A$. If $s$ is not an upper bound, then there exists $a\in A$ such that $a > s$. Since $v_n \to s$, then there exists $m$ such that $v_m < a$, contradicting the fact that $v_m$ is an upper bound. To show it is the \emph{least} upper bound, let $t < s$. Then since $u_n \to s$, we can find $m$ such that $u_m > t$. So $t$ is not an upper bound. Therefore $s$ is the least upper bound.

I don't understand how they got to the part "By the monotone sequences property, $u_n\to s$ (since $(u_n)$ is bounded above by $v_0$)".
Here's what I thought about:
From "Pick $u_0, v_0$ such that $u_0$ is not an upper bound for $A$ and $v_0$ is an upper bound." I figure these two inequalities: $\exists a \in A$ s.t. $a>u_0$ and $a \leq v_0$ $\forall a \in A$ imply $u_0 < v_0$ and consequently? $u_n < v_n$. Using this fact and from $\frac{v_n-u_n}{2}>0$ I got $u_{n+1} \geq u_n$ and $v_{n+1} \leq v_n$.
Monotone sequence propery states that if a sequence is increasing/decreasing and bounded above/below, it converges to some limit.
I just don't know how to connect the dots here? Can someone check if I wrote all inequalities correctly and how to go from here to see that $(u_n)$ is bounded above by $v_0$?

$v_n-u_n=\frac{v_0-u_0}{2^n}>0$, hence $u_n<v_n\le\dots\le v_1\le v_0$.

@AnneBauval Thanks. I am wondering how do we know $v_n \leq v_1$ what inequality are we using here?

Furthermore, I am concerned that using transitivity property "If $a ≤ b$ and $b < c,$ then $a < c$" we arrive from $u_n<v_n\leq\cdots\leq v_1\leq v_0$ at $u_n<v_0$ instead of $u_n \leq v_0$, or maybe I am misusing it?

By construction, $[u_{n+1},v_{n+1}]\subseteq[u_n,v_n]$, hence the sequence $(v_n)$ is non-increasing. As for the strictness of the inequality between $u_n$ and $v_0$, it comes from that between $u_n$ and $v_n$ (if $a<b$ and $b\le c$ then $a<c$).

Thanks, I think I got it. But if $u_n < v_0$, here $v_0$ is bound of $u_n$, shouldn't it be non-strict inequality as with bounds, i.e. a sequence is bounded if $\exists M,$ s.t. $u_n \leq M$ (where $M$ is $v_0$)?

$\exists M;\forall n;u_n\le M$ is equivalent to $\exists A;\forall n;u_n<A$: for $\implies$ take for instance $A:=M+1$, and for $\impliedby$ you can take $M:=A$.

Thanks for your help!
